# "Monchien" synonyme de "truc"?

Tags: synonymes

Je suis allé a un groupe de conversation français, et quelqu'un m'a expliqué qu'on peut utiliser le mot « truc » quand on ne sait pas le nom de quelque chose.

Il a dit que « truc » est un synonyme de « monchien ».  Je pense que j'ai  mal entendu parce que je ne peux pas trouver le mot « monchien » sur l'internet.

C'était quoi le mot qui est comme « monchien » mais n'est pas celui-ci ?

Comment: "Monchien" n'est pas un mot, effectivement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Je pense qu'il s'agit de « [machin](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/machin) » qui est sensiblement homophone à « monchien ».